# value added twice to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to populate an ArrayList after a series of test. It is working fine, but a bit too fine. It is adding each value twice to the array list. Here is my code, I don't understand where could the problem come from since I only fullresult.add once ?

```
public ArrayList<Student> filterClasses (String classe){
        ArrayList<Student> fullresult = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for (int i = 0; i < studentDB.StudentList.size(); i++) {
            int classesSize = studentDB.StudentList.get(i).classes().size()/3;
            for (int j = 0; j < classesSize ; j++){
                if (studentDB.StudentList.get(i).classes().contains(classe)){
                    fullresult.add(studentDB.StudentList.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(fullresult);
        return fullresult;
    }
```

**SOLUTION**

I did not need the second for loop:

```
public ArrayList<Student> filterClasses (String classe){
        ArrayList<Student> fullresult = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for (int i = 0; i < studentDB.StudentList.size(); i++) {
                if (studentDB.StudentList.get(i).classes().contains(classe)){
                    fullresult.add(studentDB.StudentList.get(i));
                }
            }

        System.out.println(fullresult.toString());
        return fullresult;
    }
```

Comment: replace fullresult.add(studentDB.StudentList.get(i)) with the correct index variable .get(j)

Comment: Know my tests don't work properly, the array is not full of the data I want to get.

Comment: Or you could be lazy and use a `Set` :P No more dupes

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what the code *should* be doing. I can tell you why it's wrong, but proposing a solution when I have no idea what the method should be doing is relatively impossible.

Comment: You're adding each student multiple times, depending on the number of classes, because you add them within the class loop. You need to add them outside of that loop.

Comment: I modified my code and it know works. Answer in the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really did not understand why you do

```
int classesSize = studentDB.StudentList.get(i).classes().size()/3;
```

So here is a code that will do what I believe you want:

```
public ArrayList<Student> filterClasses (String classe){
        ArrayList<Student> fullresult = new ArrayList<Student>();
        for (Student student : studentDB ) {
                if (student.classes().contains(classe)){
                    fullresult.add(student);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(fullresult);
        return fullresult;
    }
```